# Cannot set height of lightning-datatable automatically

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, scrolling, height

In my LWC, the lightning:datatable flows far off the bottom of the screen despite being inside a div with fixed height. What I really want is to set the height automatically so that it fills **the remaining height of the window**:

- On large screens or when zoomed out: More rows are displayed
- On small screens or when zoomed in: Less rows are displayed.

Instead, I have been unable to find any of the ordinary css such as height:70vh, position:absolute, etc. that you might expect to work.

Please see the Search Results datatable on the right side of the screen.

Even when the div around the datatable is set to height:350px as shown below, when zoomed in (or on small screens I expect) the table itself becomes taller than the div and rolls off the bottom of the window.

The slds-grow class is there for now in order to shrink the div to match the datatable height. With slds-grow, the SLDS flexbox sets this div to flex-grow:1 which is good... But the table still ignores the height.

When I use Inspect in Chrome here is what I find for Computed heights:

- The div around the datatable: 344px
- Drilling down into nested HTML components, nothing fishy (heights a little over 300px) ..until we get to the HTML table tag.
- table role="grid" class="slds-table slds-table_header-fixed slds-table_bordered slds-table_edit slds-table_resizable-cols" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 2280px;"> **--> computed height: 1196px**

FYI:

- This is reproducing a legacy screen, yes I know it is nonstandard. It is intended to group different objects (activities, emailmessages, and meeting notes) in one screen to enable fast on the phone support from sales cloud.
- I will also want to enable infinite scrolling, which I can figure out.
- But I do want to display scrollbars, which for some reason don't actually display though it does scroll by dragging. Thought they would appear with height being set, and there is are slds-scrollable_x and slds-scrollable_y classes evident in the html, but no scrollbars appearing..

**EDIT: **
I tried changing the orange div to:
`class="slds-grow slds-scrollable" style=" height:70%;`
This has two effects:

- Table still overflows, but not as quickly. Should div height be set using calc or from JS? Not a solution yet.
- Scrollbars do temporarily appear, only while scrolling with a click gesture. But I think it was doing this already, since another datatable without this did the same thing. The vertical scrollbar does not appear unless you are already scrolled all the way to the right end of the table which is wider than the screen.

[image: Screenshot showing how datatable overflows height of div]

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters_x-small" style="height:97%; width:100%; 
    border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color:DodgerBlue">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12" 
             style="border-style:solid; border-width:3px; border-color:MediumSeaGreen">

            <!-- Left Column panels -->
            <!-- Institution Summary panel -->
            <lightning-card title="Institution Summary" icon-name="standard:account">
                <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">                      
                    ...
                </div>
            </lightning-card>

            <!-- Contact List panel -->
            <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-p-vertical_small" 
                 style="font-weight: bold;
                        border-style:solid; border-width:3px; border-color:Violet;"
                >Contacts</div>
            <div 
            style="border-style:solid; border-width:3px; border-color:Gray;"
            >
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Right Column panels -->
        <div
        style="border-style:solid; border-width:5px; border-color:red"
        class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12">

            <!-- Filters panel -->
            <lightning-card >
                <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                style="border-style:solid; border-width:3px; border-color:Chartreuse"
                >
                    <lightning-button 
                        variant="brand-outline" 
                        label="Search and Filters" 
                        title="Open Filters Panel" 
                        icon-name={filterPanelIconName} 
                        onclick={handleFilterPanelButtonClick}
                        class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                    </lightning-button>
                    <template if:true={filterPanelIsExpanded}>
                        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
                            <p>Search Criteria</p>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <p style="height:0.5em;"></p>
                </div>
            </lightning-card>

            <!-- Search Results panel -->
            <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-p-vertical_small" 
                 style="font-weight: bold;
                border-style:solid; border-width:3px; border-color:green;">Search Results</div>
            <div class="slds-grow " style=" height:350px;
                    border-style:solid; border-width:3px; border-color:orange;">
                <lightning-datatable 
                    key-field="Id"
                    columns={searchResultsColumns}  
                    data={searchResultsData}
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    default-sort-direction={defaultSearchResultsSortDirection}
                    sorted-direction={searchResultsSortDirection}
                    sorted-by={searchResultsSortedBy}
                    onsort={onSortSearchResults}
                    column-widths-mode="fixed"
                >
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Added an edit: changed orange div to: class="slds-grow slds-scrollable" style=" height:70%;" . It still overflows, but not as quickly. This at least shows scrollbars temporarily while scrolling. Not a solution really yet.

Comment: Nobody has answered so it seems this is not really possible / a defect in datatable. I think I will have to just set the surrounding red and sea green divs to base height on children and not expect I can control the table height.